# Make a Rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms

It is as simple as it sounds I need to draw a rectangle but no matter what I do I cant seem to get it to work. This is done on a **windows form** and all I want is to **output one rectangle**, I managed to do this at school but now at home it doesn't work.

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace Rectanglr
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have connected your FormPaint method to the paint event of the form?

Comment: You should have overridden OnPaint method `protected override void OnPaint`

Comment: I am unsure what you mean do you mind explaining

Comment: FormPaint is a method to be called by an Event. For that you need to tell the form "please when you need to paint call this method where i implemented what should be painted additionally". That is normally done by adding the method to the event and that typically in the Winforms Designer or in code. In code then Something Like `this.Paint += FormPaint` in the Load Event or in the constructor after the InitializeComponent call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a project that I set up to draw a rectangle:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3))
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }
}
```

The important part to recognize here is the `partial` keyword. That's a hint that there is a second file, or maybe more, that defines this class. In this case, it's the designer file - `Form1.Designer.cs`.

If I look in the designer I can see this line:

```
  this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
```

That's the magic that makes sure this works. Without it the event isn't wired up.

Now, having said that, events are usually used by external classes to your form. The preferred approach to modify the `Paint` method is to override it.

That looks like this:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3))
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }
```

There's no need to wire this up as an event handler.

As a sidenote, please make sure you dispose every disposable in your code. A `Pen` is disposable and the `using` statement does the disposing for you.

Comment: Thanks for articulating that subtle-but-important point. Since you brought that up, it might be worth it to annotate thusly : `base.OnPaint(e); // <- This is where the Paint event is fired for external subscribers.` Then the big picture comes into focus perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You can try overriding the OnPaint method of your form:

[image: draw rectangle]

This code should do the trick:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red))
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }
}
```

It's also recommended to wrap it with a `using` block to ensure that the `Pen` resource will be properly disposed of when you are finished drawing.

Comment: If  it's still giving you trouble, you can set breakpoints in my working sample [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/draw-rectangle.git) to explore how this works.